# How to call a function using Delphi's register calling conventions from Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, delphi, visual-c++, assembly

I have a program written in Visual C++ 2012, and I was trying to call a function written in Delphi(which I don't have the source code). Here is the code in Visual C++:

```
int (_fastcall *test)(void*) = (int(_fastcall *)(void*))0x00489A7D;

test((void *)0x12345678);
```

But in the compiled code it actually was:

```
.text:1000113B                 mov     eax, 489A7Dh
.text:10001140                 mov     ecx, 12345678h
.text:10001145                 call    eax
```

And what I am excepting is:

```
.text:1000113B                 mov     ebx, 489A7Dh
.text:10001140                 mov     eax, 12345678h
.text:10001145                 call    ebx
```

I know 'fastcall' use EAX, ECX, EDX as parameters, but I don't know why Visual C++ compiler use EAX as a entry point. Shouldn't EAX be the first parameter(12345678h)?

I tried to call the delphi function in assembly code and it works, but I really want to know how to do that without using assembly.

So is that possible to let Visual C++ compiler generate code as what I am excepting? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx doesnt seem to talk about eax at all

Comment: I think you'll need to bridge it with another Delphi function that wraps the original but exposes itself using _stdcall.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was referring from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions , and I see there are more than one conventions called 'fastcall', so I just call it 'pascal'. I've modified the title. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes, the Microsoft's fastcall has nothing to do with EAX. What I am trying to do is the Borland/Embarcadero's fastcall. Don't know if that is possible

Comment: @MickeyShine: So when you know that the ms fastcall isn't what you want, why do you expect it to behave like you want?

Comment: @PlasmaHH sorry I just thought the ms compiler supports fastcall both ms way and Borland way and will automatically do the work if you link a delphi modular. I tried the 'pascal' 'PASCAL' '_pascal' modifier in my code but none of them get the expected result. Sorry if this question is not that clear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphi's [register](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) calling convention, also known as Borland fastcall, on x86 uses [EAX, EDX and ECX registers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control#Register_Convention), in that order.

However, Microsoft's fastcall calling convention uses different registers. It does not use EAX at all. Instead it uses ECX and EDX registers for first two parameters, as [described by the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx).

So, with that information you could probably write some assembler to make a Delphi `register` function call from C++, by moving the parameter into the `EAX` register. However, it's going to be so much easier to let the Delphi compiler do that. Especially as I imagine that your real problem involves multiple functions and more than a single parameter.

I suggest that you write some Pascal code to adapt between `stdcall` and `register`.

```
function FuncRegister(param: Pointer): Integer; register; external '...';

function FuncStdcall(param: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := FuncRegister(param);
end;

exports
  FuncStdcall;
```

Then you can call `FuncStdcall` from your C++ code and let the Delphi compiler handle the parameter passing.

Comment: Cool. But I am not a pro of delphi, I'll take some time to try and follow what you said. Thank you